# iOS app has background thread stuck in infinite loop

Tags: ios, multithreading, debugging

I have an app that, seemingly randomly, has a background thread that gets stuck in an infinite loop.

When the app gets into this state the main thread still continues to run fine, but I notice, my CPU % sky rockets to 100% and the memory usage continues to go up until eventually the app crashes with a memory error after the app reaches around 600 mb of memory or so.

My question is, once the app gets into this state, how can I figure out where the thread is executing or what exactly it's doing?  I can only see that a thread is running but I can't see what exactly it's executing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this happen while running the app through Xcode? If so, click the "pause" button in the debugger when this happens and look at the stack trace for the offending thread.

Comment: You should use Xcode Instruments, take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/Introduction/Introduction.html there are multiple tools able to monitor memory, threads and CPU usage.

Comment: Can you reproduce with Xcode attached? If so, reproduce, hit the pause button and see in the stack trace what is going on.

Comment: @rmaddy Hahahaha, almost 1:1 wording.

Comment: I can reproduce it with xcode running.  Ive tried instruments, thats how i saw it was happening in the first place.  which tool will show me the thread thats stuck?  @rmaddy I will try this and see what happens.

Comment: Instruments will show you *where* your app is spending most of its time. If your app is spending a lot of time in this background thread, Instruments will highlight that. The debugger, on the other hand, will let you step through the code an instruction at a time and determine *why* you get into that state. So, you'll probably use Instruments first to narrow the problem down, and then the debugger to analyze the problem.

Comment: I've managed to pause the app when stuck in this state, and it may not be in a loop, but it seems to be hung on a 'mergeChagnesFromContextDidSaveNotification'